# Is there a way to determine if a certain query need to have an index?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to know if there is a command in `mysql` (phpmyadmin) to determine if a certain query needs an index.

For example I have this kind of query:

```
SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE lastname = 'jobs' ORDER BY date_joined DESC
```

Then, when I run this query, a message will pop up and say "You can add an `index` to `column_name` to increase the speed".

Comment: Take a [look](https://sentryone.com/plan-explorer)

Comment: The query is missing the `FROM` clause. Are `lastname` and `jobs` columns of the same table?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Sorry for the mistake. `lastname` is a column, `jobs` is one of data that is inserted in `lastname` column.

Comment: So it is `'Jobs'`?

Comment: yes, as an example only.

Comment: My [_index cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) comes up with virtually the same answer as ypercube's, and appies to many more situations.

Comment: The short answer to your title question is "no".  Indexing, including "whether to" and "which column(s)" and "what order", is too complex to automate.  Your example needs a composite index; I could produce a situation where the _same pattern_ would shun all indexes as being useless.

Answer (score 5):

**Query:**

```
SELECT name
FROM table_name 
WHERE lastname = 'jobs' 
ORDER BY date_joined DESC ;
```

**Indexes:**

- `(lastname)`
  normal index for this type of queries, a simple index on the column in `WHERE`. It covers all queries that have `WHERE last_name = 'some_vale'` and will be quite efficient, assuming that the condition is "selective" enough, i.e. that you don't have millions of people with last name 'Jobs':
- `(lastname, date_joined)`
  a slightly different index, has the column in the `ORDER BY` as well. It will perform almost identically to the above index, except it will not require a sort. This is unlikely to be helpful, in most cases.
- `(lastname, date_joined, name)`
  a slightly better index, has the column from the `ORDER BY` and the `SELECT` lists. It will be slightly more efficient than the normal index, as it is "covering" completely the query. It won't need any sorting and all the values needed will be read from the index, without additional lookups in the main table. Whether this is needed, depends on the requirements about efficiency (will reducing the run time from 20 ms to 5 ms make any difference?).
  It will however not be better when the query changes, for example by adding another column in the `SELECT`list. So it is an index directed for a very narrow case.

**What to do?**

As a conclusion, you most probably only need a simple index on `(last_name)`.

> Do I need an index?

Yes, if these queries are common, the difference between not having an index and having one will be the difference between a full table scan and an index seek (with a few additional lookups in the table).
In terms of complexity, that's `O(n)` vs `O(logn)`, where n is the size of the table, assuming the default B-tree indexes.

Comment: Oh! Thanks, this is very helpful to me. I read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447987/why-cant-i-simply-add-an-index-that-includes-all-columns/5448055#5448055, although this is not `mysql`. I found out that there are `indexes` called like `per-column index` and `multiple-column index`. I quite understand it as how it explained in the link. But I still can't figure it out how to apply it on my queries. If you have the time, I asked a new question on where I add an `index` in my column/s. Here is the link, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160547/where-do-i-use-index-to-my-queries.

Comment: You don't apply the index to a query. You add the index on the table and queries (afterwards) may use it or not.

Comment: If you mean the http://use-the-index-luke.com/ site, yes it is awesome. Go and read all the pages. Twice.

Comment: Very good, ypercube.  Here's a 4th:  * `INDEX(date_joined)` -- in some situations this will be preferred simply because it would avoid the sort.