# What column/s do I need an index for my queries?

Tags: mysql, index

I need to know where to put `indexes` in my queries. I am at lost as how to use it although I am searching about this for quite some time now.

Here are my queries: (in PHP)

1) In `operator`, I do use `>` and `=`. I use `=` often.

`SELECT {columns} FROM {table}
      WHERE {field} {operator} {value}`

2) This query is for pagination, `limit` is always equal to **10**.

```
SELECT {columns} FROM {table}
  WHERE {field} {operator} {value}
  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT {start}, {limit}
```

3) This query is for checking the sent and received emails to and from other users.

```
SELECT {columns} FROM {table} alias1
  WHERE (alias1.{field} = {value} or alias1.{field2} = {value})
    AND EXISTS (SELECT max(alias2.date) alias_date FROM {table} alias2
       WHERE alias1.{field} = alias2.{field}
         and alias1.{field2} = alias2.{field2}
       GROUP BY {field}, {field2}
       HAVING alias1.date = alias_date)
       ORDER BY alias1.date DESC
```

4) A query using `IN`.

```
SELECT {columns} FROM {table}
  WHERE {field} IN ({in_data})
  ORDER BY FIELD ({field}, {in_data})
```

5) Query using `ASC`. Data in `IN` are numeric.

```
SELECT {columns} FROM {table}
  WHERE {field} IN ('in1', 'in2')
  ORDER BY date ASC
```

6) Query using `AND`.

```
SELECT {columns} FROM {table}
  WHERE {field} {operator} {value}
    AND {field2} {operator2} {value2}
```

7) Query with `DESC`.

```
SELECT {columns} FROM {table}
  WHERE {field} {operator} {value}
  ORDER BY date DESC
```

In where column/s do I need to use `index`? The important column//s that in need of `index`? I need some help.

**Note**

The `{field}` and `{field2}` are only one field, e.g. `WHERE {lastname} = {value}`.

**Update**

I posted a more detailed query from my codes and how to implement `index` based on how I understand it. Here is the link: [Are the index here will suffice to make the query faster?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160662/are-the-index-here-will-suffice-to-make-the-query-faster)

Comment: In general with your sample, the {field} could be indexed for better performance.  Beyond that, however, your generic code does not provide much information to reach a decision.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the response! What information do you need? I will edit my question anytime.

Comment: Agreed with RLF, the fields that are passed to these queries would be obvious starts, but if that's a large number (or all fields) then that's not practical.  I'd say, look at performance.  Look at the most used queries, I'm not a MySQL dev, but in MSSql you can review system tables to tell you which queries are run the most often and which ones are the most expensive.  Then you can focus on those.  Note, that if you index just the field(s) in your where clause you might still need to add columns for those in your select.

Comment: Thanks for the response, mostly, the `field` is only one field, only #4 and #6 have multiple `field`: `field` and `field2`. And what do you mean by _Note, that if you index just the field(s) in your where clause you might still need to add columns for those in your select._, I am not that good in english so I do not understand what you meant in your last sentence.

Comment: #2 is the most used query in my queries.

Answer (score 2):

Most of your answers are [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).  But here are some notes:

- `=` is easier to index than `>` (or other inequalities).  For that reason, you list of cases is much amplified.
- Using `OFFSET` (under the guise of `LIMIT {start}. ...`) requires scanning all the skipped rows.  So, see if you can "remember where you left off" as in [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).
- Please use fake names instead of `{...}`; even `a`, `b` would be easier to read and parse.
- `WHERE a op 3` -- usually can use `INDEX(a)`
- `WHERE a = 3 ORDER BY b` -- use `INDEX(a,b)`, but
- `WHERE a > 3 ORDER BY b` -- won't get past the "range"; that is, `INDEX(a,b)` will work, but the `b` part will not be used.
- I don't think `HAVING` ever factors into indexing.
- `IN ( constants )` is somewhere between `=` and `>` for index-ability:
- `WHERE a IN (constants) AND b > 8` *might* use both parts of `INDEX(a,b)`, but
- `WHERE a IN (constants) ORDER BY b` *cannot* use both parts of `INDEX(a,b)`
- If `{columns}` is a short enough list, then consider a "covering" index.  (See my first link.)
- `ORDER BY`:  `ASC` vs `DESC` *usually* does not matter; but
- `ORDER BY a ASC, b DESC` cannot use `INDEX(..., a, b)` because the directions are different.  (Version 8.0 has a solution; I assume you are not there yet.)
- `OR` is rarely optimizable -- that is it usually defies index usage.
- Your case #6 has 4 sub-cases for operators; see my link.  Hint: The order of `ANDs` does not matter, but the order of columns in a composite index does.

Etc, etc.

One more thing... If you have most of those cases hitting the same table, it becomes tricky to devise the optimal set of indexes.  Note

- `INDEX(a)` is redundant if you have `INDEX(a,b)`
- There is a limit of 64 indexes on a table, but it is unwise to have more than, say, a dozen.

If you want more specifics, (and my blog does not suffice), please provide specific schema and queries.

**"Case 2 is most popular"**

*If* `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` and *if* it is in date order:

```
WHERE a = const
  AND id <= $left_off
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 11

INDEX(a, id)

WHERE a > const
  AND id <= $left_off
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 11

(PK suffices)
```

Notes:

- By switching from `date` to `id` (if possible), the "left off" logic becomes much simpler.
- `LIMIT 11` - 10 to show, 1 to see if there is any more.  (This makes the UI more friendly, rather than linking to an empty next page.)
- See the second link for more discussion.

Comment: Thank you, this is really informative, I am currently reading your blog.

Comment: I added more specifics on your most popular case.

Comment: I read a lot of times that I need to update the index, when `INSERTING`, `DELETING` or `UPDATING`, why is that? Then I also have a problem of how to make a `per-column index` and `multi-column index` in phpmyadmin. And, switching from `date` to `id` might be possible.

Comment: `INSERT`, etc, automatically update all the indexes for the table; no manual action is needed.  (It may be necessary for some other database, not MySQL.)

Comment: Learn the mysql commandline tool.  `ALTER TABLE foo ADD INDEX(a,b);`  Or you can do that from the phpadmin window that lets you type arbitrary commands.

Comment: Thanks, I read your first and 2nd link, I will provide a more specific queries of my codes then I will also provide to what column I will add an index, this will be based on from what I understand while studying about indexes, so you can correct me if I made a mistake.

Comment: I'll gladly critique it.  It _may_ be better to start a new Question rather than clutter this one with old and new questions and old and new answers.

Comment: I made the new question here it is, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160662/are-the-index-here-will-suffice-to-make-the-query-faster.

Comment: In pagination, I will only do this based in example here, `WHERE id = left_off ORDER BY id DESC`. this is okay right?

Comment: `<=` or `<`, not `=`.