# Are the index here will suffice to make the query faster?

Tags: mysql, index

This is the continuation of the question, [What column/s do I need an index for my queries?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160547/what-column-s-do-i-need-an-index-for-my-queries), as Rick James advices me to ask a new question.

Here is the simpler code from my queries, and how will I implement the `index` in the column based on from what I understand while studying about it.
**Note:** `fields` and `values` are changed for example purposes only.

1) INDEX in `id`

```
SELECT a, b ... FROM users_table WHERE id = '1'
```

2) INDEX in `user_email`

```
SELECT a, b ... FROM users_table WHERE user_email = 'me@email.com'
```

3) INDEX in `user_link`

```
SELECT a, b ... FROM users_table WHERE user_link = 'www.somelink.com'
```

4) INDEX in `user_recover_link`

```
SELECT a, b ... FROM users_table WHERE user_recover_link = 'code'
```

5) INDEX in `id`, **side note:** I may try Rick James' answer related for pagination.

```
SELECT a, b ... FROM posts_table WHERE id > 0 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

6) INDEX in `id`

```
SELECT a ... FROM posts_table WHERE id > 0
```

7) INDEX in `category`

```
SELECT a, b ... FROM posts_table WHERE category = 'some-category'
     ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

8) INDEX in `category`

```
SELECT a, b ... FROM posts_table WHERE category = 'some-category'
```

9) INDEX in `post_url`

```
SELECT a, b ... FROM posts_table WHERE post_url = 'some-url'
```

10) INDEX in `user_url`

```
SELECT a, b ... FROM users_table WHERE user_url = 'some-url'
```

11) INDEX in `user_id`

```
SELECT a ... FROM posts_table WHERE user_id = '1' ORDER BY date DESC
```

12) INDEX in `user_id`

```
SELECT a ... FROM posts_table WHERE user_id = '1'
```

13) INDEX in `msg_receiver_id, msg_sender_id, date`

```
SELECT a, b FROM msgs_table m1
    WHERE (m1.msg_receiver_id = '1' OR m1.msg_sender_id = '1')
      AND EXISTS (SELECT max(m2.date) maxDate FROM messages m2
            WHERE m1.msg_receiver_id = m2.msg_receiver_id
              AND m1.msg_sender_id = m2.msg_sender_id
            GROUP BY msg_receiver_id, msg_sender_id
            HAVING m1.date = maxDate)
    ORDER BY m1.date DESC
```

14) INDEX in `id`

```
SELECT a, b ... FROM users_table WHERE id IN ('1', '2', ...)
    ORDER BY FIELD (id, '1', '2', ...)
```

15) INDEX in `msg_url`

```
SELECT a, b ... FROM msgs_table
    WHERE msg_url IN ('some-url-1', 'some-url-2')
    ORDER BY date ASC
```

16) INDEX in `msg_receiver_id, msg_status`

```
SELECT a, b ... FROM msgs_table
    WHERE msg_receiver_id = ?
      AND msg_status = 'unread'
```

**NOTE:** Since `id` is a `PRIMARY KEY` I do not need to use `index` anymore. Is this an *okay* to increase the queries speed performance?

Comment: These are not "Dumb Questions", they are good questions for noobies to study and learn from.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1,2,3,4,9,10 -- all the same pattern; all good.  The `PRIMARY KEY` qualifies as an `INDEX` (and `UNIQUE`).

The PK is often faster than a secondary key.  So, do not add `INDEX(id)` to a table that already has `PRIMARY KEY(id)`.  There can be only one PK on a table.

6 - good

7,11 - Needs improvement:  Composite `INDEX(category, date)`, `INDEX(user_id, date)`

8,12 - handled by indexes for 7,11

14,16 - OK as you state.

*edit* 15 - `INDEX(msg_url, date)`

13 - discussed in the other thread

To summarize:

`users_table`:

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),
INDEX(user_email),
INDEX(user_link),
INDEX(user_recover_link)
```

`post_table`:

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),
INDEX(category, date),  
INDEX(post_url),
INDEX(user_url),
INDEX(user_id, date),
INDEX(msg_receiver_id, msg_sender_id, date)
```

`msg_table`

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),  ??
INDEX(msg_receiver_id, msg_status),
INDEX(msg_url, date)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51919/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-james-are-the-index-here-will-suffice-to-make-the-q).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, and I'll explain why:

1. In a typical RDBMS, unless you change the default, a PK is going to yield a clustered index, so your ID (PK) is an index already!
2. You mention you want to add indexes, but you don't mention if it is a clustered index or non-clustered.
3. The rationale/logic behind indexing depending entirely on the CONTENT and USAGE of the database/table, and not on the schema. For example, if the field name contains 3000 rows, but just 2 distinct values, then you'd be silly to create a clustered index.

Comment: InnoDB really needs a `PRIMARY KEY`.  In MySQL, a PK is, by definition, clustered and `UNIQUE`.

Comment: *"In a typical RDBMS, unless you change the default, a PK is going to yield a clustered index"* Not really, unless "typical" means "SQL Server or MySQL". And the question is specifically about MySQL, so I wonder why you need to comment about "typical DBMS"

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL form a vast majority of database platforms out there - therefore, quite *typical* :P